# How to query through page content and compare specific text with post titles in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying automatically replace text on a page with a link if a line of text matches a post title. 
I have a magazine website with pages for each issue and with table of contents on it as a page content, also I have posts with articles (sometimes they can have 1-2-3 published articles for each issue). I want Wordpress to query through ToC text on an issue page and see if any of the titles (for now lines separeted with just 
) match titles of the posts (article) and if so replace the title with a link to an article. 
Is there a nice way to do it?
Will appreciate any input.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a way to go through a post line by line and compare those lines to posts titles I have and then replace a line in a post which got a match with a link to a matching page. Is it possible to extract from post content array each single line (lines probably should be marked somehow to let WP know that it's a line).

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this. Put below function in function.php

```
<?php
        function my_function( $post_id ){                
            if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

                // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
                remove_action('save_post', 'my_function');

                // update the post, which calls save_post again     
                $content_post = get_post($post_id);
                $arr = get_post_meta($post_id, 'link-array', false);
                foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                 $post_title_updated=str_replace( $key, $value, $content_post->post_title);
                $post_content_updated=str_replace($key, $value, $content_post->post_content);
                 }

                      $my_post = array(
                          'ID'           => $post_id,
                          'post_title'   => $post_title_updated,
                          'post_content' => $post_content_updated,
                      );

                    // Update the post into the database
                      wp_update_post( $my_post );

                // re-hook this function
                add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
            }
        }
        add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
        ?>
```

> for custom fields operation check link [Custom Fields](https://www.mageewp.com/wordpress-custom-fields.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it looks like I have to manually add a string I want to replace each time, no? I want to make it work dynamically. Am I missing something?

Comment: maintain string and link array to globally call in local function and replace thr array

Comment: Im sorry, I don't get it... Can you elaborate, please.

Comment: I see, thanks again. But I still dont understand how $arr=array("test"=>"#"); will get the data, except manually?

Comment: i added custom fields(link-array) to each post, so now you can manage link-array dynamically for each post. check blog link for more. check updated ans

Comment: Yes. But I dont really want to involve a custom-field. Do you know if there is a way to go through a post line by line? Get each line from a post and then just compare and replace?

Comment: then use dom parser to fetch all html and replace each time with links when it render.